# Can I use XAMPP while previously installed MYSQL workbench?

Tags: xampp, mysql-workbench

I have previously installed MySQL workbench. Now today I installed XAMPP  when I tried to run PHP/Admin it refused. I've changed the port to 3010 (as workbench using 3306) but still it refusing. What to do? 
Can I use MySQL workbench and XAMPP seperately ? I don't want to use the inbuilt MYSQL(Maria DB) provided by XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just start up XAMPP without MariaDB.

Comment: How would I connect Workbench with XAMPP?

Comment: I'm not getting your question but here is few things you need to know.

1. MySQL and MariaDB basically the same.

2. MySQL workbench is a tool for user to interact with database, a SQL Client like phpMyAdmin.

3. Did you replaced your MySQL database while you installing XAMPP?