# Already have MySQL WorkBench, therefore didnt select MySQL while installing XAMPP, how to connect to WorkBench from XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

I have already installed MySQL workbench years ago and still it works fine with PHP - I have been using NetBeans for PHP development.
But few days back, I installed XAMPP, and I didn't select "MySQL" while installing XAMPP as I already have MySQL WorkBench. Now how can I link XAMPP with my MySQL WorkBench? I read through [Using XAMPP and Mysql Workbench together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57774867/using-xampp-and-mysql-workbench-together) and [Can I use XAMPP while previously installed MYSQL workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919816/can-i-use-xampp-while-previously-installed-mysql-workbench) but I could not get the answer.

This is the screen shot of the XAMPP control panel :

[image: XAMP Control Panel]

Do I have to select MySQL also while installing XAMPP eventhough I have MySQL WorkBench installed in my laptop ?
Please guide me....
Thank you.

Comment: You need to set path for MySQL bin and enable MySQL via XAMPP config. You will find it on the topmost config button on right

Comment: Mysql workbench is a client side tool. It allows you to _connect to_ a mySQL server, but it does not provide one. It's presence doesn't guarantee that you also have an existing mysql server running on your machine, that is separate. So you need to check if mysql server is already present on your machine, and if not you should install it with xampp. You don't connect anything to workbench, you connect (and workbench connects) to mysql. Please ensure you understand the basic architecture of your setup and what the different applications are for

Comment: It's also likely (in the event that MySQL server is 'installed') that your version of MySQL is rather out of date.